# (How) Can we make our mobile phone to make a sound when we get pinged in chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

Sometimes it is more customary to work in chat rooms, and as there are less chances for synchronous conversation we usually ping users. When we are on computer and get pinged, we get a sound like "bhatt", it helps us a lot (for some people it is annoying) for example: if we are away from computer, say on another desk, and so a sound will make sure that you're pinged.

But on mobile phone there is no sound when we get pinged, so there are chances that we miss the pings. Can we do something so that our mobiles too make a sound?

Comment: I don't see this happening, since the chat is only accessible through a browser, which will sometimes suspend the tab (if inactive or in the background) depending on your browser, your settings, your operating system, and your phone. So in effect this might be doable for a chat window that is already open and currently in view, but then why do you need the audio cue?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Audio cue makes sure that you need not to check every minute that if you have been pinged. It helps if you are working and have kept the phone beside you. It happens so much in chat that people say “I will be back in 10 minutes and ping you” or “I will ping you when I get free” so an audio cue helps.

Comment: Using the mobile app, I get pings from chat... if you don't, perhaps your settings do not allow notifications from the app.

Comment: @rschwieb one problem with this is that the app is no longer supported, so you can’t count on it being there forever. OP might be able to use the desktop site on the phone, though I haven’t tested if you get the pings https://www.techbout.com/request-desktop-version-website-iphone-ipad-17699/

Comment: @CalvinKhor I didn’t know that! No wonder it is now a bit buggy

Comment: I just tested the desktop site on an iPad with negative results. @rschwieb yeah its a real shame :(

Comment: If you're using Chrome on your mobile phone(Android), I suggest you open the chat windows with the desktop site setting turned on. Just click on the 3 dots next to the number of tabs and scroll down to find the checkbox for "Desktop site". After checking that box, you'll be good to go. It works for me.(Just make sure your "media" volume is turned up)

Comment: @sai-karthik I’m not using android, it’s IOS. And how can we type in full site mode in chats? It’s too uncustomary to use full site mode in chats.

Comment: @Knight mind rephrasing your comment? I don't understand. On the current version of iOS you request the desktop site by holding down on the "Aa" symbol to the left of the URL. Also can someone else test with iOS, because I think somethings not right with my current setup